# What approach is best for aligning text above inputs?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to produce a formula input with value descriptions above the input elements. Below is what I am trying to reproduce:

[image]

I sketched out roughly how I wanted the formula elements to work:

https://jsfiddle.net/CumminsJP/rLt48z89

But I failed to consider the labels that must be positioned above the formula values. Which in some cases would overlap the next element on the second row--I don't know what to call that.  Although I suspect it is a question with answer that is already on SO, but I don't know what to search on.

Since I am not an experienced HTML/CSS guy, my first instinct would be to use a table.  What approach should I be looking at? (I have many other formulas that I will need to build like this one).

Code that SO is making me post because of the jsfiddle link:

```
<div>

  <span class="formula-char">((</span>
  <input class="formula-input" style="width: 50px;" />
  <span class="formula-char">-</span>
  <span class="formula-char">(</span>
  <input class="formula-input" style="width: 50px;" />
  <span class="">✕</span>
  <input class="formula-input" style="width: 50px;" value="0.3" />
  <span class="formula-char">)</span>
  <span class="formula-char">)</span>
  <span class="">✕</span>
  <input class="formula-input" style="width: 50px;" value="6400" />
  <span class="formula-char">)</span>
  <span class="">✕</span>

  <span class="formula-char">(</span>
  <input class="formula-input" style="width: 30px;" value="7.48" />
  <span class="" style="font-size: 130%;">÷</span>
  <input class="formula-input" style="width: 30px;" value="12" />
  <span class="">✕</span>
  <input class="formula-input" style="width: 50px;" value="1000" />
  <span class="formula-char">)</span>

  <span class="formula-char">=</span>
  <input class="formula-input" style="width: 50px;" value="1000" />
  <span class="">kgal/year</span>

</div>



.formula-input {
  font-size: 100%;
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

.formula-char {
  font-size: 200%;
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-right: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap each group of elements that needs a label centered over it in an element set to `display: inline-block; position: relative;` then add a `label` in that element and `absolute`ly position it above and to the center. Then add a padding to the top of the element that wraps this line to make space for the absolutely positioned label.

Here's an example with the first couple of labels in your screenshot.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 2em;
}

.formula-input {
  font-size: 100%;
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

.formula-char {
  font-size: 200%;
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-right: 1px;
}

.group {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.group label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <div class="group">
    <span class="formula-char">((</span>
    <input class="formula-input" style="width: 50px;" />
    <span class="formula-char">-</span>
    <span class="formula-char">(</span>
    <label>some label</label>
  </div>

  <div class="group">
    <input class="formula-input" style="width: 50px;" />
    <span class="">✕</span>
    <input class="formula-input" style="width: 50px;" value="0.3" />
    <span class="formula-char">)</span>
    <span class="formula-char">)</span>
    <label>some label</label>
  </div>
  
  <span class="">✕</span>
  <input class="formula-input" style="width: 50px;" value="6400" />
  <span class="formula-char">)</span>
  <span class="">✕</span>

  <span class="formula-char">(</span>
  <input class="formula-input" style="width: 30px;" value="7.48" />
  <span class="" style="font-size: 130%;">÷</span>
  <input class="formula-input" style="width: 30px;" value="12" />
  <span class="">✕</span>
  <input class="formula-input" style="width: 50px;" value="1000" />
  <span class="formula-char">)</span>

  <span class="formula-char">=</span>
  <input class="formula-input" style="width: 50px;" value="1000" />
  <span class="">kgal/year</span>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I never used transform before, but I can see that coming in handy.

Comment: @Jay you're welcome. It's awesome. Transform is also really performant and alongside `opacity`, the property you should use in `animation` and `transition`.